# In postgres, how do I find records within a range, and then a single record outside the range on both sides?

Tags: postgresql, datetime, range

I have a table in a DB with three fields: `id`, `value` and `timestamp`.

Given two dates, I know how to write a query in postgres that, using the `timestamp` field, will find all records within a range. The trouble is, I also want to find the single closest record *before* the range, and the single closest record *after* the range.

So, if I had this table:

```
id | value | timestamp
---+-------+---------------------
 1 |     18| Jan, 1 2017, 09:00:000 
 2 |     16| Jan, 1 2017, 09:05:000
 3 |     14| Jan, 1 2017, 09:21:150
 4 |     12| Jan, 1 2017, 10:01:150
 5 |     13| Jan, 1 2017, 10:07:000
 6 |     09| Jan, 1 2017, 10:23:000
```

I want to write a query that takes in the times:
`Jan, 1 2017, 9:10:000` until `Jan, 1 2017, 10:05:000`

and will return:

```
id | value | timestamp
---+-------+---------------------
 2 |     16| Jan, 1 2017, 09:05:000
 3 |     14| Jan, 1 2017, 09:21:150
 4 |     12| Jan, 1 2017, 10:01:150
 5 |     13| Jan, 1 2017, 10:07:000
```

`id 2`, is the closest record to the bottom of the range, but is still less than the bottom of the range. `id 5`, is the closest record to the top of the range but is still greater than (or equal to) the top of the range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use three unions:

```
select * from table where timestamp between start_ts and end_ts
union all
(select * from table where timestamp < start_ts order by timestamp desc limit 1)
union all
(select * from table where timestamp > end_ts order by timestamp limit 1)
```

All of those subqueries are compliant to the index on `timestamp` column.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do it with `UNION`

```
 WITH cte as (
      SELECT * 
      FROM YourTable 
      WHERE timestamp BETWEEN @start AND @end
 ), nearStart as (
      SELECT * 
      FROM YourTable 
      WHERE id = (SELECT Max(id)
                  FROM YourTable
                  WHERE id < (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM cte))
 ), nearEnd as (
      SELECT * 
      FROM YourTable 
      WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(id)
                  FROM YourTable
                  WHERE id > (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM cte))
 )
 SELECT * FROM cte
 UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM nearStart
 UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM nearEnd
```

Comment: Juan, your answer is too complicated. And it assumes that id-s are in the same order as timestamps

Comment: @DanielVidić There is nothing complicated there, but abelisto answer is simpler. You can change id for timestamp if id arent order, but then should add one index for timestamp